# Can I upload a photo via Windows Phone on Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, upload, windows-phone

I'm developing a photo sharing application and I want that people that own a Nokia Lumia will be able to upload photos. Is there a way? Do IE on WP support photo uploading?

Comment: Have you Googled `Can I upload a photo via Windows Phone on Internet Explorer?` I see some good answers there (that suggest that you indeed can upload photos on that device). Please always consider doing that first. Thanks!

Comment: Really? Not getting much in my search...

Comment: My results just talks about Skydrive, can you link it please? Is there an hack on Skydrive that I'm missing?

Comment: I get this: [My windows phone doesn't allow me to select a file to upload from the browser](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1) which indirectly confirms that you can upload images (but only images)

Comment: Ah - I misread the source. Plus yeah, the search results aren't as conclusive as I initially thought, so I retract my comment above about Googling....

Comment: Here is official confirmation that it's not supported: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/08/internet-explorer-10-brings-html5-to-windows-phone-8-in-a-big-way.aspx

Comment: I understand the exact opposite, am I wrong? "File upload functions in browsers assume you have full access to the file system. With WP you do not have unfettered access to the file system on the phone. Therefore, until IE9 allows you to choose from the locations on the phone where you do have access, this isn't possible. Perhaps in IE10? Those details aren't released yet IIRC."

I understood that you can't, not that you can.....

Comment: @Jules yeah, I misread the page.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for the effort, maybe the next time don't rush ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Phone IE browser does not support uploading of anything, whether it be images or files.

https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1/my-windows-phone-doesnt-allow-me-to-select-a-file-to-upload-from-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of Windows Phone 8.1.

http://winsource.com/2014/02/13/windows-phone-8-1-file-upload-google-calendar/

Comment: Note that in WebViews using IE 11 on WP 8.1 it is still not supported